# Adding a delete button to a list

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, dom, appendchild

Trying to add a delete button to a to do list using javascript DOM manipulation. The problem is when I appendChild() in my for loop. It only appends the button I created to the last list item.

```
<div id="list">
    <ul>
        <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook</li>
        <li>Jello</li> 
        <li>Spinach</li>
        <li>Rice</li>
        <li>Birthday Cake</li>
        <li>Candles</li>
    </ul>
</div>

var item = document.querySelectorAll("li");
var button = document.createElement("button");
var buttonText = document.createTextNode("delete");
button.appendChild(buttonText);
for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    item[i].appendChild(button);
}
```

Comment: Can't you just directly add an inline button in your HTML?

Comment: @AdilRaza yeah I could, but the list is interactive and not static. So using DOM manipulation to eventually create buttons automatically as more items are entered into the list on the browser. Thank you for the input though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one button exists so you are moving it from `li` to `li` and it ends up in the last one.  You can create a new button each iteration so they all get a delete button.

```
var item = document.querySelectorAll("li");

for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    var buttonText = document.createTextNode("delete");
    button.appendChild(buttonText);
    item[i].appendChild(button);
}
```